# npm install not installing any packages

Tags: gruntjs, npm

Im trying to test an old project, and when i run npm install, all i get is:

```
npm WARN package.json xx@ No repository field.
npm WARN package.json xx@ No license field.
```

My package.json file looks like this:

```
{
"name": "xx",
"version": "",
"dependencies": {},
"devDependencies": {
  "connect-livereload": "~0.3.2",
  "grunt": "~0.4.1",
  "grunt-bg-shell": "~2.3.1",
  "grunt-contrib-csslint": "^0.2.0",
  "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.8.1",
  "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.6.0",
  "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
  "grunt-newer": "^0.8.0",
  "grunt-ngrok": "^0.2.2",
  "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.2.1",
  "time-grunt": "~0.2.7"
},
"engines": {
  "node": ">=0.8.0"
}
```

}

I havent run this kind of install in a while and im afraid im forgetting something, any ideas as to what ?

EDIT: it turns out the folder copy i had of the project had already a node_modules folder with everything installed, reason why running npm install wasnt doing anything. Although i thought there would be some kind of warning or message saying all modules are installed already.

Answer (score 2):

Getting the warning is not a concern. If you can see a structure of npm packages being installed after the warning, then it works fine. In case you want to avoid these warning, you can add `respository` and `license` fields to your package.json.

```
 "repository": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "git://github.com/user/repo.git"
 },
 "license": "ISC"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a bracket from the end

```
{
"name": "xx",
"version": "",
"dependencies": {},
"devDependencies": {
  "connect-livereload": "~0.3.2",
  "grunt": "~0.4.1",
  "grunt-bg-shell": "~2.3.1",
  "grunt-contrib-csslint": "^0.2.0",
  "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.8.1",
  "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.6.0",
  "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
  "grunt-newer": "^0.8.0",
  "grunt-ngrok": "^0.2.2",
  "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.2.1",
  "time-grunt": "~0.2.7"
},
"engines": {
  "node": ">=0.8.0"
}
}
```

I sugges you to use `npm init` then install the packages by the cli-tool
for eg:

**save to devDepencies**

`npm install connect-livereload grunt grunt-bg-shell ... --save-dev`

**save to depencies**

`npm install express ... --save`

read more at: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the folder copy i had of the project had already a node_modules folder with everything installed, reason why running npm install wasnt doing anything. Although i thought there would be some kind of warning or message saying all modules are installed already.